# How to find Roku IP + Port on network using SSDP search in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, roku, ssdp

I am trying to find my *Roku TV* on my network and apparently it needs some SSDP discovery based on [Roku API help](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API), however, I am unable to search for my device with any of the Nuget libraries.

I came across [**ssdpradar**](https://github.com/PingmanTools/SsdpRadar) and was able to install the Nuget package for Visual Studio (VB.NET) through Visual Studio 2017 community release. However, I am not able to find any documentation on how to use it.

Any advice would be helpful.

**Solution:**

I found a solution but not with **ssdpradar** and rather [**RSSDP**](https://github.com/Yortw/RSSDP). After you add the nugget in your project you can use the following line of code to get all devices and then find the Roku location (ip+port) from that list.

```
Imports Rssdp

For Each founddevice As DiscoveredSsdpDevice In founddevices.Result
    If founddevice.Usn.Contains("roku:ecp") Then
        Rokulocation = founddevice.DescriptionLocation.ToString()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully use a library called [RokuDotNet](https://github.com/philliphoff/RokuDotNet) recently. It's written in C# but you could load it as a project in your solution and reference it from VB.NET.

This is roughly the way I used it:

```
Imports RokuDotNet.Client

Public Class Form1
    Private _discoveryClient As RokuDeviceDiscoveryClient

    Public Sub New()
        _discoveryClient = New RokuDeviceDiscoveryClient
        AddHandler _discoveryClient.DeviceDiscovered, AddressOf DiscoveryHandler
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        _discoveryClient.DiscoverDevicesAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub DiscoveryHandler(sender As Object, e As DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs)
        If InvokeRequired Then
            BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() DiscoveryHandler(sender, e)))
            Return
        End If

        ' Get the display name for the device (if the user entered one when setting it up)
        Dim deviceInfo = Await e.Device.Query.GetDeviceInfoAsync
        Dim name = deviceInfo.UserDeviceName
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) Then
            name = deviceInfo.ModelName
        End If
        AddDevice(e.Device, name)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddDevice(device As RokuDevice, name As String)
        ' Your code here
    End Sub
End Class
```

You might want to add a try/catch around the await in that async function so it can show an error if there's a network problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @libertyernie. I'll try it out and will update the post.

Comment: I tried this method and it was not successful. It says that the component build is not compatible with my Framework. @libertyernie